# Show modal dialog in parallel thread

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading

I need to show window with spinner, during processing some action.
This Window should be model, so I am using ShowDialog() method:

```
 void ShowDlg() {
        Thread WindowThread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        SpinnerWindow spinnerWindow = new SpinnerWindow();
        spinnerWindow.ShowDialog();
        System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
    });
        WindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        WindowThread.Start();
 }
```

Then after some process is done, I am trying to close this modal window:

```
                WindowThread.Interrupt();
            if (!WindowThread.Join(2000))
            { 
                WindowThread.Abort();
            }
```

and everything works well, until I try to call ShowDlg() second time. I am getting next exception:

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

What I am doing wrong, maybe incorrect close of created thread?

Answer (score 2):

You are probably calling the `ShowDialog` from within another thread again. When that's the case you should invoke your main form like this:

```
mainForm.Invoke(spinnerWindow.ShowDialog());
```